TestContainers: Can not connect to Ryuk at localhost:50517 after upgrade to macos to Sequoia 15
As a demo project, I use the following:
https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-java-spring-boot-quickstart,
Information about Java and Docker versions is below:
java -version
openjdk version "21.0.4" 2024-07-16
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Homebrew (build 21.0.4)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Homebrew (build 21.0.4, mixed mode, sharing)

and Docker:
docker version
Client:
 Version:           27.2.0
 API version:       1.47
 Go version:        go1.21.13
 Git commit:        3ab4256
 Built:             Tue Aug 27 14:14:45 2024
 OS/Arch:           darwin/arm64
 Context:           desktop-linux

Server: Docker Desktop 4.34.2 (167172)
 Engine:
  Version:          27.2.0
  API version:      1.47 (minimum version 1.24)
  Go version:       go1.21.13
  Git commit:       3ab5c7d
  Built:            Tue Aug 27 14:15:41 2024
  OS/Arch:          linux/arm64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          1.7.20
  GitCommit:        8fc6bcff51318944179630522a095cc9dbf9f353
 runc:
  Version:          1.1.13
  GitCommit:        v1.1.13-0-g58aa920
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.19.0
  GitCommit:        de40ad0

mvn verify:
14:51:41.924 [main] INFO  org.testcontainers.dockerclient.DockerClientProviderStrategy - Loaded org.testcontainers.dockerclient.UnixSocketClientProviderStrategy from ~/.testcontainers.properties, will try it first
14:51:42.060 [main] INFO  org.testcontainers.dockerclient.DockerClientProviderStrategy - Found Docker environment with local Unix socket (unix:///var/run/docker.sock)
14:51:42.061 [main] INFO  org.testcontainers.DockerClientFactory - Docker host IP address is localhost
14:51:42.070 [main] INFO  org.testcontainers.DockerClientFactory - Connected to docker: 
  Server Version: 27.2.0
  API Version: 1.47
  Operating System: Docker Desktop
  Total Memory: 7838 MB
14:51:42.080 [main] INFO  tc.testcontainers/ryuk:0.5.1 - Creating container for image: testcontainers/ryuk:0.5.1
14:51:42.250 [main] INFO  org.testcontainers.utility.RegistryAuthLocator - Credential helper/store (docker-credential-desktop) does not have credentials for https://index.docker.io/v1/
14:51:42.302 [main] INFO  tc.testcontainers/ryuk:0.5.1 - Container testcontainers/ryuk:0.5.1 is starting: 8ea1bb2f94ea72d9248e75babaf4a3e1be825deb49e66891e32896fd33cb1eb6
14:51:42.485 [main] INFO  tc.testcontainers/ryuk:0.5.1 - Container testcontainers/ryuk:0.5.1 started in PT0.411918S
14:51:42.490 [testcontainers-ryuk] WARN  org.testcontainers.utility.RyukResourceReaper - Can not connect to Ryuk at localhost:50517
java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write0(Native Method)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:62)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.tryWrite(NioSocketImpl.java:394)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.implWrite(NioSocketImpl.java:410)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.write(NioSocketImpl.java:440)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl$2.write(NioSocketImpl.java:819)
        at java.base/java.net.Socket$SocketOutputStream.write(Socket.java:1195)
        at java.base/java.io.OutputStream.write(OutputStream.java:124)
        at org.testcontainers.utility.ResourceReaper$FilterRegistry.register(ResourceReaper.java:389)
        at org.testcontainers.utility.RyukResourceReaper.lambda$null$0(RyukResourceReaper.java:109)
        at org.rnorth.ducttape.ratelimits.RateLimiter.doWhenReady(RateLimiter.java:27)
        at org.testcontainers.utility.RyukResourceReaper.lambda$maybeStart$1(RyukResourceReaper.java:88)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)

I can't prove it but I have a feeling that the issue appeared the first time right after MacOS upgrade to the latest version: Sequoia 15.
Any ideas for troubleshooting to identify the root cause of the issue with Ryuk are welcome.

The root cause of the issue was ESET. After the uninstallation of ESET, any problems with TestContainers disappeared.
